# How to access instance variable from its "string name"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, metaprogramming, instance-variables

Is there a way (meta programmation ?) to read/write an instance variable when we just know its string name ?

For instance I have a @my_var instance variable used within a class method.
During the process, I will hapen to have a string "my_var" that tell me to change the @my_var instance variable.

Of course I could use a "if" statement, but I want it to be more dynamic as I will have potentially many different instance variables in my method.

I was thinking of something with **"my_var".classify** and something else...

Does anybody has a clue ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `instance_variable_set` and `instance_variable_get`. Keep in mind the string needs to have the leading `@`:

```
@foo = "bar"
# => "bar"
instance_variable_get("@foo")
# => "bar"
instance_variable_set("@foo", "baz")
# => "baz"
@foo
# => "baz"
```